# Javascript working only after opening developer tool on any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, magento, firefox

I know this is an old question but I didn't get proper solution for this problem. I am using `magento`. In that I have one phtml file for slider. I have used `flexsider` and now trying `swiper.js`. But the problem is both of them are not working properly. I mean when I refresh page slider did not work but when I open developer tool or firebug it works. I have tried with firefox and chrome and getting same problem on both browsers.
Anyone know this issue? Or at least can anybody tell me where is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) try placing debugger; in first line of your js script tag 
2) open developer tools in chrome or any browser
3) check whether breakpoint works
4) need more help then upload the code some place mention the link in your question

hope this helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Ctrl+Shift+F5 is your friend.

Secondly, This sounds like a cache problem. If you have enabled caching on your static assets in any way, you need to change that. There are certainly good and effective caching solutions on any development stack, but yours seems to cause problems.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. but still it's giving the same error. Even on my mobile it's the same error. It's like opening developer tool is triggering something and the slider starts working smoothly. Also I am using magento theme which is using same slider on the same page and it's working fine. The problem is with my slider. I did check the code if there is any missing link but everything seems perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I've been stuck on this problem for 2 days and finally found the fix!

Reference: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters

Just set `observer` parameter to `true`.

```
const params = {
  loop: true,
  speed: 1000,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 5000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  observer: true,
  renderPrevButton: () => (
    <button className="swiper-button-prev ht-swiper-button-nav">
      <FiChevronLeft />
    </button>
  ),
  renderNextButton: () => (
    <button className="swiper-button-next ht-swiper-button-nav">
      <FiChevronRight />
    </button>
  ),
};
```

This enables Mutation Observer on Swiper and its elements, which makes the Swiper update (reinitialize) each time you change its style (like hide/show) or modify its child elements (like adding/removing slides).